# Twilio - 12200 Schema validation warning Description Invalid content was found starting with element 'HangUp'. One of '{Play

Tags: twilio-api

I am getting the following error from Twilio.

> 12200 Schema validation warning Description Invalid content was found starting with element 'HangUp'. One of '{Play

POST URL:http://b0dd02a0.ngrok.io/MSservice/PostCall

The markup is formed like this.

```
<Response>
  <Say>Hi</Say>
  <HangUp/>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add the explicit hang up call.

Change your response to

```
<Response>
  <Say>Hi</Say>
</Response>
```

The application will say Hi and then hang up because there are no more instructions.

Comment: Yes but I want to explicitly hang up the call.Is there any other way for it?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly hang up the call. It will happen automatically. If you want to reject a call use the Reject verb.